# How to make one window to block another without using .setModal(True)

Tags: python, pyqt

If main window right-clicked a `QInputDialog` shows up. I want `QInputDialog` to block main window while it is open. How to achieve this?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
        frame=QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        frame.connect(frame, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.up)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame)

        self.modal=QtGui.QInputDialog()       

    def up(self, QPos):
        self.modal.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.modal.show()
        self.modal.raise_()

window=AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, This solution can be solve by use method `QWidget.setWindowModality (self, Qt.WindowModality windowModality)` .  A modal window is one that blocks input to other windows. Note that windows that are children of a modal window are not blocked.

Add this line in your initial method;

`self.modal.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)`

Completed code is;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class AppWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
        frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        frame.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        frame.connect(frame, QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.up)
        mainLayout.addWidget(frame)
        self.modal = QtGui.QInputDialog(self)
        self.modal.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

    def up (self, QPos):
        self.modal.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        self.modal.show()
        self.modal.raise_()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Reference method** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setWindowModality

**Reference enum** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#WindowModality-enum

---

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

In a nut shell, this is the basic approach. I have created a second window (a Frame), containing a table widget, and the name of my class is TableWindow. Import that in your main window file. On a button click, I call the below function.

```
    def call_table_window(self):
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame()
        self.window_table = TableWindow()
        self.window_table.setupUi(self.frame)

        #This stops the user to switch to the main window. He has to close 
        #the 2nd window first.
        self.frame.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.frame.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Especially when working with **PyQt5**, you can set inside the `__init__`

```
self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
```